# How to write comparator function for qsort?

Tags: c++, oop

class for example:

```
class classname{
public:
int N,M;
};
```

classname a > classname b if a.N>B.N

Comment: In C++, is there any way in which `qsort()` is superior to `std::sort()`?  The latter is type-safe, more intuitive, and generally faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class classname{
  public:
    int N,M;

    bool operator< (const classname& other) const { return N < other.N; }
};

...
std::vector<classname> arr;
...
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

Or do you want to use C's `qsort`?

```
static int compare_classname (const void* a, const void* b) {
   const classname* _a = reinterpret_cast<const classname*>(a);
   const classname* _b = reinterpret_cast<const classname*>(b);
   return _a->N < _b->N ? -1 : _a->N > _b->N ? 1 : 0;
}
...
classname* arr = new classname[n];
...
qsort(arr, n, sizeof(arr[0]), compare_classname);
```

Comment: Why? qsort is old and busted. std::sort is the new hotness

Comment: What's "busted" about `qsort` ?

Comment: @Charles: type safety + speed. Compare the speed of qsort to std::sort

Comment: For most uses of `qsort` type safety isn't usually a concern (it's a simple "bounce" through a `void*`), unless you're accepting random function pointers from code that you don't trust. And yes, std::sort _can_ be faster and also works with non-POD types. But how does any of this make `qsort` "busted" for its intended purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using C++, my advice would be to use std::sort instead of qsort. In this case, you normally implement your comparison function as `operator<`:

```
class classname { 
public:
    int N, M;

    bool operator<(classname const &other) const { 
        return N < other.N;
    }
};
```

Edit:
If you insist on using C's qsort, the comparison function looks something like this:

```
int comparator(void *a, void *b) { 
     return ((classname *)b)->N - ((classname *)a)->N;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
struct Functor {
   bool operator()(const classname & left, const classname & right) {
       return left.N < right.N;
   }
}

std::sort(container.begin(), container.end(), Functor());
```

Comment: I think technically `operator()` should be `const`. (And you would inherit from `std::binary_function`)

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically want to use `qsort`, then the function would be

```
int compare_classname(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return static_cast<const classname*>(a)->N 
         - static_cast<const classname*>(b)->N;
}
```

But as others have said, you're better off with `std::sort`. It's typesafe, and probably faster since it can inline the comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

In case you really want to you C's `qsort` (which you shouldn't if you use C++):

```
int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return static_cast<classname*>(a)->N < static_cast<classname*>(b)->N;
}
```

Then just pass compare as the 4th argument of `qsort`

Comment: As it stands, this won't compile. A static_cast needs a type in angle brackets before the value to be cast.

Comment: Thanks. The code was actually right, just my formatting was wrong. I didn't know that <> parts get discarded when one only uses <pre></pre> instead of the 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
#include <stdlib.h>


class classname{
public:
    int N,M;
};

static int
cmp_classname(const void * p1, const void * p2) 
{
    const classname * pc1 = reinterpret_cast<const classname *>(p1);
    const classname * pc2 = reinterpret_cast<const classname *>(p2);
    if (pc1->N < pc2->N) {
        return -1;
    } else if (pc1->N > pc2->N) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And, yes, std::sort() is probably better.